# Making a browser with flutter

Tags: flutter, browser, webview, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I made a browser with **flutter WebView** and enabled **JavaScript** and this is my code for the browser screen.

The main goal for the app is to automate a website (Movies Website) to let the app see the ads of the website but in the background and the app will download the movie by scrapping for the its download link in the HTML page viewed in the WebView of my the flutter app.

BrowserScreen.dart

```dart
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class BrowserScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const BrowserScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BrowserScreen> createState() => _BrowserScreenState();
}

class _BrowserScreenState extends State<BrowserScreen> {
  late WebViewController controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My browser'),
      ),
      body: WebView(
        onPageStarted: (url) {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print(url);
          }
        },
        initialUrl: 'https://rank.egybest.org/',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onPageFinished: (url) {
          // here i will run the javascript code to perform something like scrapping and automation
        },
        onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
          this.controller = controller;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**But the website** detects that I am using a WebView and shows a message to use a browser like (Chrome, FireFox ...)
How to make my flutter app provides what chrome does for that website to make it open normally into my WebView.

**If there** is another way to scrap the website without flutter WebView Please Help me.

The WebSite Link is
https://yes.egybest.works/

If the link doesn't open with you , Use a VPN in the middle east.

**This is** A screenshot of my app

***Translation of this image (Please use a famous website .Chrome, Firefox...)***
[image: The error that happens in my flutter webview]

Comment: what features/websites do not work?

Comment: https://rank.egybest.org/   if it didn't open with you use a vpn to be in the middle east

Comment: @MindStudio https://rank.egybest.org if it didn't open with you use a vpn to be in the middle east

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MindStudio I edited my question , please help me.

Answer (score 1):

websites can detect **WebView** by checking **userAgent** or **http-headers**..

so you can set user-agent like:

`WebView(userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0",..)`