# A browser with flutter for android

Tags: flutter

Please help me with this question.
I asked this question once but I got no help , so I am asking again .
And I hope somebody will help me.

[Making a browser with flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71978280/14893686)

Comment: Since you've asked the question already and your question is open please open another question asking the same Question. 
Please see [How to ask a Good StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for ways in which you can improve your original question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making a browser with flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71978280/making-a-browser-with-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use webview   [webview_flutter: ^3.0.2](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)

or check the below plugins for your sample browser app

https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_browser_app.git

https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview

Comment: this website detects that browser, and refuse to open on it,...

Comment: is there any way to use the flutter_inappwebview package and open chrome and run javascript on it?